# Allow Git in File Explorer After Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, git-bash

I have installed Git using the Visual Studio 2015 installer.

Unfortunately, it looks like installing it this way did not add the "Git bash here" feature to File Explorer, which is a feature that I used heavily back when I installed Git manually.

Is there any way to add this feature back without reinstalling manually?

Comment: Are you sure that VS 2015 comes with Git Bash? I think it´s a separate installation: https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: Oh, that's entirely possible.  So should I just install the latest version of Git for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Git bash here" should be provided by the setup (not the portable version) of [git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/).

Its [releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) include:

[`v2.7.0.windows.1/Git-2.7.0-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.0.windows.1/Git-2.7.0-64-bit.exe)

Or, 18 months later: [`v2.14.1.windows.1/Git-2.14.1-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.1.windows.1/Git-2.14.1-64-bit.exe).

Comment: Guess I kind of forgot about this question.  I came across it again while Googling this same issue again for VS2017!  So are you saying that the Visual Studio Installer installs the _portable_ version of Git for Windows, which does not include Git bash, and that that is why the "Git bash here" shell integration feature is not available?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 Yes, the "git bash here" is only added by the setup: now in 2017, https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.1.windows.1/Git-2.14.1-64-bit.exe (instead of PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe)

Comment: bummer... I'd like to install through VS because having Git for Windows be continuously updated is nice, but losing the "Git bash here" feature is kind of a deal breaker :/